# Global keyboard shortcut to switch to an application (to use with Emacs/Aquamacs)

Tags: keyboard, applescript, emacs

Like in iTerm, I'd like to be able to set a keyboard shortcut to switch to an application, which in this case would be Aquamacs. This would be really useful to know in general. Would an Applescript or Automator let me do this?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use specifically Applescript/Automator to avoid 3rd party applications, but eventually I utilised capabilities of application called *Alfred* (I can not recall right now, but there is a chance you should buy Alfred Power Pack to use this feature)

In addition with the help of Karabiner.app I forced *CapsLock* button to act as *Shift+Cmd+Ctrl+Opt* and there is almost no need to use *Opt+Tab* to switch between apps since then.

[image: Alfred / Workflows]